# Getting errors in pip install picamera

Tags: picamera

Running setup.py clean for picamera

```
Failed to build picamera
Installing collected packages: picamera
  Running setup.py install for picamera ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\a\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Teja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\\picamera\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nl7jig75\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\picamera\setup.py", line 101, in run
        with io.open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as cpuinfo:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\picamera\setup.py", line 145, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\picamera\setup.py", line 140, in main
        cmdclass             = {'install': CustomInstallCommand},
      File "C:\a\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\a\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\picamera\setup.py", line 113, in run
        raise ValueError('Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo')
    ValueError: Unable to open /proc/cpuinfo
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\a\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Teja\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\\picamera\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nl7jig75\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Teja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4jgy3jv6\picamera\
```

please help me in fixing up this issue

Answer (score 4):

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
```

That directory is missing. I don't think that you can install PiCamera on Windows.

Comment: I get the same error on OSX, which is UNIX-based.